# Selenium Javascript Webdriver: how to setup Firefox profile to accept selfsigned certificate

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

I'm trying to use `selenium-webdriver` to test a site that uses a self-signed certificate.

To pass the tests under Firefox, it is required to use a profile that tells Firefox to accept the self-signed certificate.

I was able to use a profile created using `firefox -ProfileManager`. However, I'm not able to use a profile that is created programmatically.

Can anybody tell what I'm missing here?

Here is the `javascript` program that uses the profile created by `firefox -ProfileManager`:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var firefox   = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var profile   = new firefox.Profile('/path/to/firefox/profile');
var browser   = new firefox.Driver(new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile));

browser.get('https://self-signed.badssl.com/');
browser.quit();
```

And here is the `javascript` program that uses the profile created by code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var firefox   = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var profile   = new firefox.Profile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCerts(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertIssuer(false); // `true` didn't work too
var browser   = new firefox.Driver(new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile));

browser.get('https://self-signed.badssl.com/');
browser.quit();
```

The error I'm getting with the second program is as follows:

```
$ node test-firefox-profile.js
/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:654
    throw error;
    ^

WebDriverError: Error loading page
    at WebDriverError (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:10)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:477:11)
    at parseHttpResponse (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:386:15)
    at /user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:328:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(https://self-signed.badssl.com/)
    at Driver.schedule (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:414:17)
    at Navigation.to (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1042:25)
    at Driver.get (/user/ws/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:832:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user/ws/test-firefox-profile.js:9:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Comment: Hi @Younes, did you find any solution? I am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't. As indicated in the question, I'm able to get the same result using a profile created with the ProfileManager. As I haven't been able to solve this issue, I'm falling back to the predefined profile.

Comment: Hi @Younes, check this link with my solutions for ff and phantomjs. Maybe it will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638830/selenium-webdriver-phantom-and-firefox-ssl-issue

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.
`driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'firefox', acceptSslCerts: true, acceptInsecureCerts: true});`

Answer (score 2):

When [answering](//stackoverflow.com/a/43704394/962603) another question, I stumbled upon this question. Eventually I figured out the answer.

What worked for me was using the [`Builder`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Builder.html) instead of trying to use a [`firefox.Driver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index_exports_Driver.html):

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox'),
    driver = null,
    profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCerts(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertIssuer(false);

var opts = new firefox.Options();
opts.setProfile(profile);
var builder = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox');
builder.setFirefoxOptions(opts);
driver = builder.build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
driver.quit();
```

Of course, all methods of the [`firefox.Profile`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index_exports_Profile.html) can be used before setting it in the [`firefox.Options`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index_exports_Options.html) and passing those to the builder.

Note that the builder will still return an instance of a `firefox.Driver`.

Comment: it gives me error

profile = new firefox.Profile();
              ^

TypeError: firefox.Profile is not a constructor

Comment: I think firefox.Profile has been removed - see https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox - instead one should use `.setFirefoxOptions`