# How do I get selenium-webdriver to ignore SSL errors in Firefox and PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, ssl, phantomjs

Given these Node dependencies:

```
{
    "chromedriver": "^2.24.1",
    "cucumber": "^1.3.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.12",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0-beta-2"
}
```

I would like PhantomJS and Firefox to ignore SSL certificates. Here is how my browser.js looks:

```
require('geckodriver');

// main browser object
var browserHandle;

// load selenium webdriver and some rules
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), 
    By = webdriver.By, 
    until = webdriver.until;

// load phantomjs into webdriver capabilities
var phantomjs_exe = require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path;
var customPhantom = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
customPhantom.set("phantomjs.binary.path", phantomjs_exe);

webdriver.Builder()
    //.forBrowser('firefox')
    //.forBrowser('phantomjs')
    .withCapabilities(customPhantom)
    .build();
```

Any suggestions with `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes`? How can I implement it in the code? I want to use only JavaScript, rather than Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is only for Javascript / Node.js Selenium Webdriverjs case, only MacOS solution.

1. Firefox case:

   a. Setup a new Profile using the Profile Manager for Firefox.

   - Open the Profile Manager with `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P` (`-profilemanager`, this works as well)
   - Click "Create Profile"
   - In the second Step of creation, the Path to the Profile File is displayed. Copy it!

   b. Add the ffprofile File

   - Go to features/support
   - Add a new File "ffprofile.json"
   - add { "ffprofile": "`<profilePath>`"} to the file, where `<profilePath>` is the Path you copied in `a.`

   c. Add your local system to the Profile

   - Open the Profile Manager again with `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P`
   - Select your new Profile, click "Start Firefox"
   - In the Browser, go to your `https://...`. You should see a Page telling you there is a Problem with the certificate
   - Click on "Advanced" -> "Add Exception" -> "Confirm Security Exception"

   d. Add this into your browser.js or where you call a browser programmatically:

   ```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), 
   firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox'),

   var ffProfileFile = require('./ffprofile');
   var ffProfile = new firefox.Profile(ffProfileFile['ffprofile']);
   var ffOptions = new firefox.Options().setProfile(ffProfile);

   return browserHandle = new firefox.Driver(ffOptions);
   ```
2. Phantomjs case ( I have got two solutions here, pick up the one which is better for you):

   solution 1:

   ```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), 
   phantom = require('phantomjs-prebuilt');

   var capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
   capabilities.set(webdriver.Capability.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   capabilities.set(webdriver.Capability.SECURE_SSL, false);
   capabilities.set("phantomjs.cli.args",
                    ["--web-security=no",
                     "--ssl-protocol=any", 
                     "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"]
                   );
   return browserHandle = new webdriver
   .Builder()
   .withCapabilities(capabilities)
   .build();
   ```

   solution 2:

   ```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), 
   phantom = require('phantomjs-prebuilt');

   var capabilities = {
       'browserName' : 'phantomjs',
       'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true',
           '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false']
   }
   return browserHandle = new webdriver
   .Builder()
   .withCapabilities(capabilities)
   .build();
   ```

   for this one the `'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']` did the job for me.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: FYI, I found that it was enough to write `capabilities.set("phantomjs.cli.args", ["--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"]);` to get PhantomJS to load an untrusted cert.

Comment: @Chris that is awesome

Answer (score 8):

For Firefox, you can use the following code:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(Capabilities.firefox()
.set("acceptInsecureCerts", true)).build();
```

Comment: This is the only flag I needed to set in order to fix the SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER error on a Mac OS X v10.12.6, with selenium-driver v3.6.0 and geckodriver v0.19.1

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome browser, just need to set `Capability.ACCEPT_INSECURE_TLS_CERTS, true`. It is working for me.

```
const { Builder, By, until, Capabilities, Capability } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const capabilities = Capabilities.chrome();
capabilities.set(Capability.ACCEPT_INSECURE_TLS_CERTS, true);

this.driver = new Builder()
        .withCapabilities(capabilities)
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
```